# I get error in a php echo inside a javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, echo

I am getting error when I use some code inside a JavaScript file, but inserting into HTML div. I used a PHP method to show all clients, and is working fine in html page. But in JavaScript I get error in the echo.

See error in Visual Studio Code ==> https://prnt.sc/1yy4sxl

Here is my code:

```
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().children(".clientNewOrder").html(

'<div class="form-group">' +
'    <div class="input-group mb-3">' +
'        <div class="input-group-prepend">' +
'            <select class="form-control" required>' +
'                <option value="">Select Client</option>' +
'                <?php' +
'                $item = null;' +
'                $valor = null;' +
'                $selectClient = ControllerClients::ctrReadClients($item, $values);' +
'                foreach ($selectClient as $key => $value) {' +
'                    echo <option value=".$value["id"]. ">'.$value["name"]. '</option>;' +
'                }' +
'                ?>' +
'            </select>' +
'        </div>' +
'    </div>' +
'</div>'
)
```

I tried changing "" '' but problem still here.
I removed '' in echo ' ', something like this:

```
'  echo <option selected>Select</option>' +
'       <option value="01">John</option>' +
'        <option value="02">Mary</option>;' +
```

and is running ok in this manual form, but dynamically I can't handle it

Comment: Are you running this in a javascript file, or this is in php?

Comment: You can't run php code inside a javascript file.

Comment: Well, I was trying to create a select, and after you choose the new order type, in a js file I will run the php in order to show a list of clients. THis is to show a new select with the list of all clients

Comment: For the php portion of the code that is generating all the options, all the single quotes need to be removed for the `<?php` tag handling, but I'm not clear if this is within a javascript file or not?

Comment: Yes, this is a js file

Comment: it works ok, using php code, but without variables, something like this:` ----------------------------------------------------------- '                <?php' +
'                $item = null;' +
'                $value = null;' +
'                $selectClient = ControllerClients::ctrReadClients($item, $values);' +
'                foreach ($selectClient as $key => $value) {+              '      'echo  <option selected>Select</option>' +   '        <option value="36">Jhon Doe</option>;' +
   '?>' +

Comment: You can use PHP to generate JS, which will be sent to the browser; but you cannot use JS to generate PHP, because the server has already finished its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixex PHP code lines inside the JavaScript single qoutes. PHP should run as a separate block but you can generate the JavaScript single quotes using the PHP ECHO itself:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().children(".clientNewOrder").html(

'<div class="form-group">' +
'    <div class="input-group mb-3">' +
'        <div class="input-group-prepend">' +
'            <select class="form-control" required>'+
'                <option value="">Select Client</option>'
                <?php
                $item = null; 
                $valor = null;
                $selectClient = ControllerClients::ctrReadClients($item, $values);
                foreach ($selectClient as $key => $value) {
                    echo '+\'<option value="'.$value["id"]. '">' .$value["name"]. '</option>\'+'; 
                }
                ?>
'            </select>' +
'        </div>' +
'    </div>' +
'</div>'
)
```